# Transform json to ini files using jq + bash

Tags: json, bash, jq, ini

I'm trying to transform json (array of objects) to ini files:

```
[
  {
    "connection": {
      "id": "br0",
      "uuid": "ab1dd903-4786-4c7e-a4b4-3339b144d6c7",
      "stable-id": "",
      "type": "bridge",
      "interface-name": "br0",
      "autoconnect": "no",
      "autoconnect-priority": "0",
      "autoconnect-retries": "-1",
      "auth-retries": "-1",
      "timestamp": "44444",
      "read-only": "no",
      "permissions": "",
      "zone": "WAN",
      "master": "",
      "slave-type": "",
      "autoconnect-slaves": "1",
      "secondaries": "",
      "gateway-ping-timeout": "0",
      "metered": "unknown",
      "lldp": "default"
    },
    "ipv4": {
      "method": "manual",
      "dns": "192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1",
      "dns-search": "",
      "dns-options": " ",
      "dns-priority": "0",
      "addresses": "192.168.1.3/24",
      "gateway": "",
      "routes": "192.168.10.0/24 192.168.1.1",
      "route-metric": "-1",
      "route-table": "0",
      "ignore-auto-routes": "no",
      "ignore-auto-dns": "no",
      "dhcp-client-id": "",
      "dhcp-timeout": "0",
      "dhcp-send-hostname": "yes",
      "dhcp-hostname": "",
      "dhcp-fqdn": "",
      "never-default": "no",
      "may-fail": "yes",
      "dad-timeout": "-1"
    }
  },
  {
    "connection": {
      ...
    },
  }
]
```

OR

```
  {
    "connection": {
      ...
    },
  }
```

**What i tried to do is:**

**1. Transform json to strings**

```
data=$(jq -r 'def keyValue:  to_entries[] | "[\(.key)]\\n\(.value | to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)" ) | join("\\n") )\\n"; if type == "array" then keys[] as $k | "\(.[$k] | .connection.id)=\(.[$k] | keyValue)" elif type == "object" then "\(.connection.id)=\(. | keyValue)" else keys end' /tmp/json)
```

Provides:

```
br1=[connection]\nid=br1\nuuid=ab1dd903-4786-4c7e-a4b4-3339b144d6c7\nstable-id=\ntype=fff\ninterface-name=br0\nautoconnect=no\nautoconnect-priority=0\nautoconnect-retries=-1\nauth-retries=-1\ntimestamp=1525494904\nread-only=no\npermissions=\nzone=WAN\nmaster=\nslave-type=\nautoconnect-slaves=1\nsecondaries=\ngateway-ping-timeout=0\nmetered=unknown\nlldp=default\n
br1=[802-3-ethernet]\nport=\nspeed=0\nduplex=\nauto-negotiate=no\nmac-address=\ncloned-mac-address=\ngenerate-mac-address-mask=\nmac-address-blacklist=\nmtu=1500\ns390-subchannels=\ns390-nettype=\ns390-options=\nwake-on-lan=default\nwake-on-lan-password=\n....
```

**2. Walk over strings in bash**

```
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do [ "$oldkey" = "$key" ] && echo -en "$value" >> "/tmp/ini/$key" || echo -en "$value" > "/tmp/ini/$key" ; oldkey="$key"; done <<< "$data"
```

Gives:

```
[connection]
id=br1
uuid=ab1dd903-4786-4c7e-a4b4-3339b144d6c7
stable-id=
type=fff
interface-name=br0
autoconnect=no
autoconnect-priority=0
autoconnect-retries=-1
auth-retries=-1
timestamp=1525494904
read-only=no
permissions=
zone=WAN
master=
slave-type=
autoconnect-slaves=1
secondaries=
gateway-ping-timeout=0
metered=unknown
lldp=default
[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1
dns-search=
dns-options= 
dns-priority=0
addresses=192.168.1.3/24
gateway=
routes=192.168.10.0/24 192.168.1.1
route-metric=-1
route-table=0
ignore-auto-routes=no
ignore-auto-dns=no
dhcp-client-id=
dhcp-timeout=0
dhcp-send-hostname=yes
dhcp-hostname=
dhcp-fqdn=
never-default=no
may-fail=yes
dad-timeout=-1
```

I'm almost there! But is there possible to do it more "elegantly" and more performance way, avoiding pipes, external calls, etc.

**Note:** Moreover, mostly it should be done with jq + bash, because other processing tools like sed, awk is slower than i've done, but i do not reject them completely =)

**P.S.** - Main purpose of this transforming is the fast "bulk operation" to write ini files

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66564551/320399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ultimate goal is to produce several .ini files, then we can reuse `def kv` as defined in the other answer:

```
def kv: to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)";
```

The driver program would however now be:

```
.[]
| [to_entries[] | "[\(.key)]", (.value|kv)]
| join("\n")
```

Running jq with this program then yields one JSON string for each item in the array. Using the example, the first such string would be:

```
"[connection]\nid=br0\nuuid=ab1dd903-4786-4c7e-a4b4-3339b144d6c7\nstable-id=\ntype=bridge\ninterface-name=br0\nautoconnect=no\nautoconnect-priority=0\nautoconnect-retries=-1\nauth-retries=-1\ntimestamp=44444\nread-only=no\npermissions=\nzone=WAN\nmaster=\nslave-type=\nautoconnect-slaves=1\nsecondaries=\ngateway-ping-timeout=0\nmetered=unknown\nlldp=default\n[ipv4]\nmethod=manual\ndns=192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1\ndns-search=\ndns-options= \ndns-priority=0\naddresses=192.168.1.3/24\ngateway=\nroutes=192.168.10.0/24 192.168.1.1\nroute-metric=-1\nroute-table=0\nignore-auto-routes=no\nignore-auto-dns=no\ndhcp-client-id=\ndhcp-timeout=0\ndhcp-send-hostname=yes\ndhcp-hostname=\ndhcp-fqdn=\nnever-default=no\nmay-fail=yes\ndad-timeout=-1"
```

You can then iterate over these newline-delimited strings.

Comment: So easy! That's awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To convert an array as shown to the ".ini" format could be accomplished by simply using this jq program:

```
def kv: to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)";

.[]
| to_entries[]
| "[\(.key)]", (.value|kv)
```

Putting this in a file, say program.jq, then assuming the JSON shown in the question (minus the "..." part) is in input.json, the following invocation:

```
jq -rf program.jq input.json
```

yields the corresponding ".ini" file.

If you want to ensure that the program will also handle the case when there is no enclosing array, you could modify the first line in the main program above to test whether the input is an array, so you'd have:

```
if type == "array" then .[] else . end
| to_entries[]
| "[\(.key)]", (.value|kv)
```

Comment: It's ok only for one file! I don't want to iterate or call jq multiple times in bash. I need strings like this:
`br1=[connection]\nid=br1\nuuid=\n.......`

`br2=[connection]\nid=br2\nuuid=\n.......`

and so on. After this, i can use `while read` and write files separately

Comment: Please see the new answer.