# Convert JSON to simple key=value file using jq

Tags: json, config, jq, ini

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  ...
  "keyn": "valuen"
}
```

No arrays or nested objects, just a simple key->value map. I want to use `jq` to convert this file to a plain text configuration file of a following format:

```
KEY1=value1
KEY2=value2
...
KEYn=valuen
```

(the keys should be uppercased in the result file). I have searched various `jq` tutorials available on the Net expecting that such an obvious (in my opinion) example would be covered there (at least without uppercasing), but it is not. All tutorials I have found use more complicated examples, like extracting specific values from JSON file, handling arrays or nested structures etc. However, no simple JSON-to-text conversion. `man jq` doesn't help either, it's not too clear. Could you help me in obtaining the result I want?

Note: it must be done with `jq`, not any other tool, because it will be used in a script that has access to `jq`, but no other tool for handling JSON is guaranteed to be present on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the entries in the object with `to_entries`, then format each to a string and use the `-r` (--raw-output) flag, like so:

```sh
$ cat example.json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "keyn": "valuen"
}
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | (.key | ascii_upcase) + "=" + .value' < example.json
KEY1=value1
KEY2=value2
KEYN=valuen
```